# Attempting to inline Java into Perl via the Inline::Java module

Tags: java, perl, perl-module

This is my first attempt to inline Java code in Perl. We cannot use the standard SFTP command on our system. This is out of my power. We have a jarfile called SFTP.jar which can be used. The previous person before me was able to get Inline::Perl to work, but his implementation was sloppy, and I'd like to clean it up.

I am working on a Windows system on the `H:\svn` directory. I have my module under the `H:\svn\FMS3` directory, and I have a jarfile called `SFTP.jar` under the `H:\svn\FMS3\Sftp.pm` directory. There is a file called `Sftp.pm` located under the `H:\svn\FMS3` directory, and defines a module called `FMS3::Sftp`. (I'm keeping all of our custom modules under the `FMS3` parent module).

I have inlined code in `FMS3::Sftp`, and it looks like it compiles. However, when I attempt to execute, it claims `Can't exec JVM: open3: Can't call method "close" on an undefined value at C:/Perl/lib/IPC/Open3.pm line 370`.

Exactly what am I doing wrong?

The `FMS3::Sftp` module:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
# Sftp.pm
########################################################################


########################################################################
# PACKAGE FMS3::Sftp
#
package FMS3::Sftp;
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# PERL PRAGMAS
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw($PERL_CLASSPATH);
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# CONSTANTS
#
use constant {
    FTP_SERVER => "10.85.10.190",
    FTP_USER => "fisaftp",
    FTP_PASSWORD => "Fisa123456",
};
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# INITIALIZE
#
# Set a PERL_CLASSPATH that will include all directories in the
# @INC array. Somewhere in this array will be located our JAR file
# that we need to include, and of course, this classpath.
#
# This will be appended to the standard $CLASSPATH environment variable.
#
BEGIN {
    use Config;

    my $cpsep;
    if ($Config{osname} =~ /^mswin32/i) {
        $cpsep = ";";
    } else {
        $cpsep = ":";
    }

    $PERL_CLASSPATH = join("/FMS3/Sftp/SFTP.jar$cpsep", @INC);
    $PERL_CLASSPATH = "$PERL_CLASSPATH/FMS3/Sftp/SFTP.jar";
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# 
# PERL INLINE JAVA CODE:
#
use Inline (
    Java => 'DATA',
    J2SDK => $ENV{JAVA_HOME},
    CLASSPATH => $PERL_CLASSPATH,
    STUDY => ["SFTP", "close", "list", "get", "put", "remove"],
    DEBUG => 4,
);
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# CONSTRUCTORS
#
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $server = shift;
    my $user = shift;
    my $password = shift;

    if (not $server)   { $server = FTP_SERVER;     }
    if (not $user)     { $user = FTP_USER;         }
    if (not $password) { $password = FTP_PASSWORD; }

    my $self = {};
    bless($self, $class);

    eval {$self->{CONNECTION} = new SFTP($server, $user, $password);};

    if ($@) {
        $self->{ERROR} = $@;
        return;
    }

    return $self;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# DESTRUCTOR (Automatic close on losing $self)
#
sub DESTROY {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->{CONNECTION}->close();

    return 1;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
#  List
#
sub List {
    my $self = shift;
    my $location = shift;

    my @list;

    eval {@list = $self->{CONNECTION}->list($location);};

    if ($@) {
        $self->{ERROR} = $@;
        return;
    }

    return @list;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# Get
#
sub Get {
    my $self = shift;
    my $file = shift;
    my $location = shift;

    eval {$self->{CONNECTION}->get($file, $location);};

    if ($@) {
        $self->{ERROR} = $@;
        return;
    }
    return 1;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# Put
#
sub Put {
    my $self = shift;
    my $file = shift;
    my $location = shift;
    my $mode = shift;

    eval {$self->{CONNECTION}->put($file, $location, $mode);};

    if ($@) {
        $self->{ERROR} = $@;
        return;
    }
    return 1;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# Remove
#
sub Remove {
    my $self = shift;
    my $file = shift;

    eval {$self->{CONNECTION}->remove($file);};

    if ($@) {
        $self->{ERROR} = $@;
        return;
    }
    return 1;
}
#
########################################################################

########################################################################
# Error
#
sub Error {
    my $self = shift;

    return $self->{ERROR};
}
#
########################################################################
1;
__DATA__
__Java__
import com.trilead.ssh2.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class SFTP { 

    ConnectionInfo ci;
    SCPClient sftp=null;
    SFTPv3Client sftpv3=null;
    Connection conn=null;

    public SFTP(String host, String username, String password) {
        boolean b=false;       
        conn= new Connection(host);

        try {
            ci=conn.connect();
            b=conn.authenticateWithPassword(username,password);

            if (!b) {
                System.out.println("Invalid login.");
                System.exit(0);
            } 

            sftp = new SCPClient( conn );
            sftpv3 = new SFTPv3Client (conn);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to connect"+": "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void close()
    {
        conn.close();
    }  

    public String[] list (String loc)
    {
        Vector v=null;
        SFTPv3DirectoryEntry x=null;
        try 
        {
            v = sftpv3.ls(loc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Pickup location does not exist, please check!"); 
            String[] value = new String[1];
            return value;
        }

        String[] s=new String[v.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
            x = (SFTPv3DirectoryEntry)v.elementAt(i);
            s[i]=x.filename;
        }
        return s;
    }

    public void get (String file, String loc)
    {
        try{
            sftp.get(file,loc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to download, please check location or file permissions");
        }        
    }

    public void put (String file, String loc, String mode)
    {
        try{
            sftp.put(file,loc,mode);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to put"+": "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void remove (String file)
    {
        try{
            sftpv3.rm(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to remove"+": "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I have a test program called test.pl which looks like this:

```
use FMS3::Sftp;
my $ftp = FMS3::Sftp->new();
print $ftp->List(".");
```

All I am trying to do is connect to our server and do a list of the directory. However, I am getting classpath errors when attempting to run `test.pl`

```
[perl][1] validate done.
[perl][1] Starting build.
[perl][4]    portable: ENV_VAR_PATH_SEP_CP for MSWin32 is ';'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => H:\svn for MSWin32 is default 'H:\svn'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar for MSWin32 is default 'C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar'
[perl][2]  classpath candidate 'C:/Perl/site/lib/FMS3/Sftp/SFTP.jar' scraped
[perl][2]  classpath candidate 'C:/Perl/lib/FMS3/Sftp/SFTP.jar' scraped
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => H:\svn\FMS3\Sftp\SFTP.jar for MSWin32 is default 'H:\svn\FMS3\Sftp\SFTP.jar'
[perl][2]  classpath: H:\svn;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar;D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar;C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar;H:\svn\FMS3\Sftp\SFTP.jar
[perl][4]    portable: J2SDK_BIN for MSWin32 is 'bin'
[perl][4]    portable: EXE_EXTENSION for MSWin32 is '.exe'
[perl][4]    portable: IO_REDIR for MSWin32 is '2>&1'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => H:\svn\_Inline\lib\auto\FMS3\Sftp_7ae5 for MSWin32 is default 'H:\svn\_Inline\lib\auto\FMS3\Sftp_7ae5'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_CMD_QUOTES => "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation  -d "H:\svn\_Inline\lib\auto\FMS3\Sftp_7ae5" SFTP.java > cmd.out 2>&1 for MSWin32 is default '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation  -d "H:\svn\_Inline\lib\auto\FMS3\Sftp_7ae5" SFTP.java > cmd.out 2>&1'
[perl][2]  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javac.exe" -deprecation  -d "H:\svn\_Inline\lib\auto\FMS3\Sftp_7ae5" SFTP.java > cmd.out 2>&1
[perl][4]    portable: COMMAND_COM for MSWin32 is '0'
[perl][2]  classpath: .;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar;D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar
[perl][1] build done.
[perl][1] Starting load.
[perl][4]    portable: ENV_VAR_PATH_SEP_CP for MSWin32 is ';'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => H:\svn for MSWin32 is default 'H:\svn'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar for MSWin32 is default 'D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_JAVA_PATH => C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar for MSWin32 is default 'C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar'
[perl][2]  classpath: H:\svn;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2java.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\sqlj.zip;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\db2jcc_license_cu.jar;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\bin;D:\PROGRA~1\IBM\SQLLIB~1\java\common.jar;D:\Program Files\Rational\ClearQuest\cqjni.jar;C:\Perl\site\lib\Inline\Java\InlineJavaServer.jar
[perl][1] starting JVM...
[perl][1] client/server mode
[perl][4]    portable: GOT_NEXT_FREE_PORT for MSWin32 is '0'
[perl][4]    portable: J2SDK_BIN for MSWin32 is 'bin'
[perl][4]    portable: EXE_EXTENSION for MSWin32 is '.exe'
[perl][4]    portable: SUB_FIX_CMD_QUOTES => "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java.exe"  org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer 4 localhost 7890 false false false for MSWin32 is default '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java.exe"  org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer 4 localhost 7890 false false false'
[perl][2]  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\java.exe"  org.perl.inline.java.InlineJavaServer 4 localhost 7890 false false false
[perl][4]    portable: DEV_NULL for MSWin32 is 'nul'
[perl][1] JVM owner exiting...
Can't exec JVM: open3: Can't call method "close" on an undefined value at C:/Perl/lib/IPC/Open3.pm line 370.
 at C:/Perl/site/lib/Inline/Java.pm line 484
INIT failed--call queue aborted.
[perl][1] killed by natural death.
[perl][1] exiting with 22
```

Comment: `Inline::Perl` is for embedding another Perl interpreter (say, for a different version of Perl) into a Perl script. This is an `Inline::Java` question.

Comment: Have you tried `Net::SFTP` or one of the other pure Perl SFTP clients on CPAN?  That should get around your requirement of not using the system sftp without needing to integrate multiple languages.

Comment: I tried to use Net::SFTP, but too many modules we don't have are required, and installing modules in our system is a great pain. However, I did solve my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out. I had several things wrong:

- Under Study, I had both the Methods and Class, but I only should have the Class.

### Wrong

```
use Inline (
    Java => 'DATA',
    J2SDK => $ENV{JAVA_HOME},
    CLASSPATH => $PERL_CLASSPATH,
    STUDY => ["SFTP", "close", "list", "get", "put", "remove"],
#    DEBUG => 4,
);
```

### Right

```
use Inline (
    Java => 'DATA',
    J2SDK => $ENV{JAVA_HOME},
    CLASSPATH => $PERL_CLASSPATH,
    STUDY => ["SFTP"],
#    DEBUG => 4,
);
```

- When I declare the SFTP object as `new`, I have to give it the full Perl namespace:

### Wrong

```
eval {$self->{CONNECTION} = new SFTP($server, $user, $password);};
```

### Right

```
eval {$self->{CONNECTION} = new FMS3::Sftp::SFTP($server, $user, $password);};
```

You spend several hours on something like this, give up, and then suddenly the light in the ol' dusty attic comes on. I'm a fairly smart guy. Stick a screwdriver in a live socket, and after the third or fourth time, I go "Hey, maybe that's not a good idea".

Comment: Nitpick: indirect syntax tends to be deprecated. The preferred syntax is: `FMS3::Sftp::SFTP->new()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try Net::SFTP::Foreign, if you use it with plink (the command line ssh client from the PuTTY package) you would not need any other module to get it working.

Comment: We do these things on Unix systems and Windows, so that wouldn't really work for us.

Comment: Net::SFTP::Foreign does work on both Unix and Windows using plink or openssh clients, or even the Net::SSH2 module.