# Perl calls Java

Tags: java, perl

Is there a way in my Perl script to call some Java api meaning to create a Java object and the object calls its methods to do stuff, etc. I searched the web and haven't found a solid example about it (maybe there is no way). BTW what I want is NOT to use the system calls.

Comment: [`Inline::Java`](http://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java)

Comment: No thats not what I need, what I need is to use Java code to "obtain" some information and feed that informatoin back to Perl. I know its messy but I have many exsiting perl code, don't want to throw it away. However, I would like to use some Java stuff like JAXB to load the xml information to Java and feed it to Perl. So like what I said, in Perl, create an Java obj, and calls its methods, etc.

Comment: As a matter of interest, what XML functions are you missing in Perl that you would use from JAXB?

Answer (score 0):

Read my sad, sad saga about inlining Java on this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4197693/368630).

It took me a long while to figure out the right incantations to do this. The answer to that query might be able to help.

Comment: I think this post might be more suitable as a comment than as an answer.

Comment: Just for the record, pls install Inline-0.44 or Inline-0.53, perl Makefile.PL; make; make test; make install; This will install Inline::C, I haven't figured out how to install Inline::Java

Comment: @user2167013 Inlining is one of the murkiest aspects of Perl and Perl has a lot of murk in it if you dig deep enough. It took me a long time to figure this out. Fortunately, I haven't had to do anything like this since.

Comment: Ok, got it. had to use the version 0.53 and do "cpan Inline::Java", very surprised that this is not documented anywhere in the cpan site. Even if it does, its not clear to a new user like me.

Comment: Hi Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work if you call JAXB in the perl/Java code. if you add the following JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance("Something"); , you will see the Java code in Perl never passes that line