# Perl inline::Java No public method ' ' defined for class ' '

Tags: java, perl, inline

I was looking for some help getting this bit of code to funciton correctly via perl Inline::Java.
My problem occurs when I call the stupid() method passing two arguments.
My apache log (attached below) returns  No public method 'stupid' defined for class 'main::MathFunctions'.

Note:  line 342  is `print $jfunc->stupid($tapsRe{$i},$tapsIm{$i}) . "\n";`
My other method (`twoComplimentNbit`) inside the MathFunctions class works just fine.
Can anyone point to something I'm missing here?

```
BEGIN {
$ENV{CLASSPATH} .= ":/var/www/java/commons-lang-2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar";
$ENV{CLASSPATH} .= ":/var/www/java/commons-math-2.2/commons-math-2.2.jar";
}
use Inline::Java;
use Inline (Java => <<'END_OF_JAVA_CODE', AUTOSTUDY => 1, DEBUG => 6,

import org.apache.commons.math.complex.*;
import org.apache.commons.math.MathException;
import org.apache.commons.math.transform.FastFourierTransformer;
import java.util.*;


class MathFunctions {



public static int twoComplimentNbit(int val, int bits) {
val &= (int) (1 << bits) - 1;

int R = (int) (1 << bits - 1);

if (val < R) {
return val;
} else {
return val - R * 2;
}
}




public double stupid (float REAL, float IMG) {
Complex result = new Complex(REAL,IMG);
double realOne = result.getReal();
double imgOne = result.getImaginary();
return realOne;

}


}
END_OF_JAVA_CODE
SHARED_JVM => 1,
DIRECTORY => '/tmp',
);

my $jfunc = new MathFunctions();
```

Output:

```
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][3]   packet sent is call_method 2031 MathFunctions      fastAtan2 (double,double) scalar:LTAuMDAxOTU2OTY5NjQ2MDM2Mzc= scalar:MC4wMDE5NTY5Njk2NDYwMzYzNw==
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][3]   packet recv is ok scalar:LTAuNzg1Mzk4Mg==
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][5]     stupid
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  No public method 'stupid' defined for class 'main::MathFunctions' at /var/www/pre_eq-dev.cgi line 342
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object::Tie
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][2]  destroying object in java (main::MathFunctions):
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][3]   deleting object main::MathFunctions=HASH(0x8cd4248) 2031 (MathFunctions)
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][3]   packet sent is delete_object 2031
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][3]   packet recv is ok undef:
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Protocol
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object::Private
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][1] killed by natural death.
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][1] JVM non-owner exiting...
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][1] exiting with 9
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object::Tie
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    script marked as DONE, object destruction not    propagated to Java
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Protocol
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object::Private
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    destroying Inline::Java::Object::Tie
[Fri Jun 27 16:11:45 2014] [error]  [perl][4]    script marked as DONE, object destruction not propagated to Java
```

Comment: Are you sure you call it as an object method (non-static) instead of class method (static)?

Comment: I've done this once. I couldn't get AUTOSTUDY to work, so I tried STUDY. I also put my Java code at the end of my program under `__DATA__`. You can take a look at my question, and see [how I ended up doing this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197693/attempting-to-inline-java-into-perl-via-the-inlinejava-module) to get this to work. Maybe it'll give you some ideas.

Comment: The output does not come from what you posted. Please provide a minimal, runnable demonstration of the problem, and the output from *that* code.

Comment: So this turned out to be a permissions problem. The directory where I was storing my .jar files wasnt set +r for www-data (apache user) and the build directory wasn't writable.   Thanks for your help on this.